# App read emails

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-xml, text-to-speech

I'm trying to develop app that can read emails out loud , the question is how can I create a TEXT TO SPEECH tool or somthing that can make me to reach to emails body ? I mean how can I connect the text to speech code with the text inside the email body to read it out loud ?

I'm already trying with The first steps and open the email by the web view and create the floating action button inside it but the problem is the button just appear befor I login after that it's not showing up ,how can I fix this?  This the code:

```
WebView webView;
ProgressBar progressBar;


FloatingActionButton fab_plus,fab_voice,fab_pause;
Animation FabOpen,FabClose,FabRClookwise,FabRanticlookwise;
boolean isOpen=false;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test1_main);


    webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


    fab_plus=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab_plus);
    fab_voice=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab_voice);
    fab_pause=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab_pause);
    FabOpen= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fab_open);
    FabClose= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fab_close);
    FabRClookwise= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotate_clockwise);
    FabRanticlookwise= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotate_anticlockwise);


    fab_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(isOpen){

                fab_pause.startAnimation(FabClose);
                fab_voice.startAnimation(FabClose);
                fab_plus.startAnimation(FabRanticlookwise);
                fab_voice.setClickable(false);
                fab_pause.setClickable(false);
                isOpen=false;

            }

            else {
                fab_pause.startAnimation(FabOpen);
                fab_voice.startAnimation(FabOpen);
                fab_plus.startAnimation(FabRanticlookwise);
                fab_voice.setClickable(true);
                fab_pause.setClickable(true);
                isOpen=true;

            }
        }
    });

    if(savedInstanceState != null){

        webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }
    else{
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new ourViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view ,int progress){

                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                if(progress<100 && progressBar.getVisibility()== ProgressBar.GONE){


                    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                }
                if(progress==100){

                    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                }
            }



        });

        String data=getIntent().getDataString();
        if(Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(getIntent().getAction())){


            webView.loadUrl(data);
        }

        else{

            webView.loadUrl("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1#identifier");
        }

    }
}

public class ourViewClient extends WebViewClient {


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url) {
        if(url.contains("accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1#identifier")){




            v.loadUrl(url);
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);

        }
        else{

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri),"choose broweser"));

        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(webView.canGoBack()){

        webView.goBack();
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    webView.saveState(outState);
}
```

}

And for XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="64dp"
android:paddingRight="64dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"

tools:context="com.example.test1.Test1MainActivity">


<ProgressBar

    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="8dp" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="308dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_puse"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:id="@+id/fab_pause"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/fab2_color"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="308dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_voice"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:id="@+id/fab_voice"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/fab1_color"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="308dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_plus"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:id="@+id/fab_plus"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    />
```

the second I want to do action in these buttons by TTS algorithm as I mentioned above but I dont know how I reach to the text in email body .. it possible to do such as this app in this way ?

Answer (score 0):

Use google Speech api
Goto below TTS link
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html

Comment: thanks , I know how to use TTS in general but I mean how I use it and put it inside email body and make this algorithm recognise to text inside the emails message

Comment: You mean you want to know how to call listener of TTS

Comment: yes and work it inside my mail inbox , how can I do that ?

Comment: but in webview you are not picking up the strings, Use Gmail API then get each mail seperately having full access to the text and then programmatically call TTS listener

Comment: I already tried it from this link https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android  but it not work . can I do it by Intent ?

Comment: Did you troubleshoot ?  On the starting days of Android development I spent whole week solving a single problem, Start debugging check if any points are missing